Group widgets in Gtk to display only a single widget at a time
I'm using the following code to display some stuff:
class AppWindow(Adw.ApplicationWindow):
    __gtype_name__ = 'AppWindow'

    label = Gtk.Template.Child()
    search_button = Gtk.Template.Child()
    refresh_button = Gtk.Template.Child()
    content = Gtk.Template.Child()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.search_button.connect("clicked", self.on_search_cb)
        self.refresh_button.connect("clicked", self.on_refresh_cb)


Now, I want to display only one of label, search_button, or content at a time. Is there a way to group those widgets, something like gtk_widget_set_group, that would help me reduce some code?
If not, we can always do:
def set_label_visible(self):
    self.label.set_visible(True)
    self.search_button.set_visible(False)
    self.content.set_visible(False)
...


What about defining tags along with the widgets and use them as a group marker? You can define even multiple of them if a widget is member in more than one group.

I didn't quite understand that very well. Sorry, could you elaborate?

I'm sorry, I didn't mean to offend you in any way. I didn't understand the term "tags" here.

Tagging mean to me to attach/associate properties with code objects. Python class objects allow definition of any additional properties just by assignment and then they are there ready to be queried if necessary.

Yes, you can bind the "visible" property of the three widgets using the G_BINDING_INVERT_BOOLEAN flag, but I honestly don't know if this will shorten the code that much.

Okay, that worked for me, since after the initial state, I only need the content and label widgets.
I'm just curious if this would work for more than two widgets? There would be a circular set.

No, it won't work for more than two widgets, because when A changes, B and C will change but B will try to change C and C will try to change B. I didn't realize this when I wrote the answer.
